# NodeJS http.request end processing before data processes

Tags: json, node.js, get

Can some explain why the the http.request end function is running before any data is actually retrieved?  And how would I debug this any further? Should I be checking an http status?

This is going to work with Google Home app, but I took that code out and getting same error running locally. The http.request is from what a teacher provided in a class.

You can paste: people/?search=Luke%20Skywalker 
into http://swapi.com (SW = StarWars API) to see the expected result.

```js
'use strict';
/*eslint no-undef: "error"*/
/*eslint-env node*/
/*eslint-disable no-console */
let http = require('http');
let starWarsAPI = `www.swapi.co`; 


//function to get details of the Star Wars Characters
//exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  //console.log("event=" + JSON.stringify(event));
  //console.log("context=" + JSON.stringify(context));
  //let characterName = event.result.parameters.StarWarsCharacter;
  let characterName = "Luke Skywalker";
  console.log("**** characterName=" + characterName); 
  
  let options = searchPeopleRequestOptions(characterName);
  console.log("options=" + JSON.stringify(options)); 
  
  makeRequest(options, function( data, error) {
    console.log(" Processing data.results"); 
    let person = data.results[0];
    if (person) {
        let height = person.height;
        let mass = person.mass;
        let response = person.name + " is " + height + " centimeters tall, weighs " + mass + " kilograms";
        console.log("**** response=" + response);         
        //callback(null, {"speech": response});
    }
    else {
        console.log ("No person found"); 
        //callback(null, {"speech": "I'm not sure that character exists!"});
    }
  });
//};

console.log("The end"); 
 
//create a function to read first and last names from the API.

function searchPeopleRequestOptions(argCharacterName) {
    var pathValue = `/api/people/?search=`+ 
          encodeURIComponent(argCharacterName); 
    return {
        host: starWarsAPI, 
        path: pathValue 
    };
}
 
function makeRequest(options, callback) {
    var responseString = ""; 
    var request = http.request(options, 
    function(response) {
        response.on('data', function(data) {
            responseString += data;
            console.log("responseString=" + responseString); 
        });
         response.on('end', function() {
            console.log("end: responseString=" + responseString); 
            // dies on next line because responseString is empty 
            var responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseString);
            callback(responseJSON, null);
        });
         response.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log('\n Error received: ' + error);
        });        
    });
    request.end();
}
```

This is what I see when I run it:

```
E:\GitHub\NealWalters\GoogleHomeTest
λ node indexTest.js
**** characterName=Luke Skywalker
options={"host":"www.swapi.co","path":"/api/people/?search=Luke%20Skywalker"}
The end
end: responseString=
undefined:1
```

I'm not sure what's writing out the "undefined: 1" line.

Comment: You do need to look for both errors and http response codes when you code with `http.request()`.  All of that will be simpler with the `request()` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the server's response status code, it will be [`301: Moved Permanently`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

And value of location field of response is:

> https://swapi.co/api/people/?search=Luke%20Skywalker

instead

> http://swapi.co/api/people/?search=Luke%20Skywalker

As we can see, the protocol changed from `http` to `https`.

The problem is that the http client supplied with the node.js does not support redirection for permanently changed URL.

So, you can use [`https`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) module instead `http` (just change the `require('https')`).

Or use packages that support redirection. For example [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [`request`](https://github.com/request/request).

Comment: Thanks. So code should check for non-200 status then.